# Get-request parameters in the node js (without express)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a blog in native node js and javascript, html, css. I am trying to send a get request from the main.html page to the server in order to display not all posts, but only posts of a certain rubric. I do it in the following way (see code below). But the get query doesn't work. When I click on that link on the main.html page nothing happens, and when I update page, rubric: undefined is output to the console . What am I doing wrong?

main.html (client):

```html
<body>
    <a class="rub_link" id="programming" href="#">Programming</a>
    ...
    <!-- Output of posts to html -->
    <div class="posts" id="posts">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="posts_inner">         
                {card_data}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
    <script>
        document.querySelector('#programming').addEventListener('click', onRenderProgrammingPosts)

        function onRenderProgrammingPosts(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            let body = "rubric=programming";
            request.open("GET", "/main?" + body, true);
        
            request.onload = function() {
                if (request.status != 200) {
                    alert(`Error ${request.status}: ${request.statusText}`);
                } else {
                    alert(`Done, received ${request.response} from the server`);
                }
            };

            request.send();
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

index.js (server):

```js
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

    let filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'public', req.url === '/' ? 'login.html' : req.url)
    const ext = path.extname(filePath)
    let contentType = 'text/html'

    switch (ext) {
        case '.css':
            contentType = 'text/css'
            break
        case '.js':
            contentType = 'text/javascript'
            break
        default:
            contentType = 'text/html'
    }

    if (!ext) {
        filePath += '.html'
    }

    fs.readFile(filePath, (err, content) => {
        if (err) {
            fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'error.html'), (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.writeHead(500)
                    res.end('Error')
                } else {
                    res.writeHead(200, {
                        'Content-Type': 'text.html'
                    })

                    res.end(data)
                }
            })
        } else {
            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': contentType
            })

            dbConnect()

            if (req.url === '/login' && req.method === 'POST') {
                loginApp(req, res)
            } else if (req.url === '/registration' && req.method === 'POST') {
                regApp(req, res)
            } else if (req.url === '/new_post' && req.method === 'POST') {
                createNewPost(req, res)
            } else if (req.url === '/main' && req.method === 'POST') {
                deletePost(req, res)
            } else if (req.url === '/main' && req.method === 'GET') {
                let rubric = url.parse(req.url, true).query.rubric
                console.log("rubric: " + rubric) //undefined
                renderPosts(res, rubric)
            } else {
                res.end(content)
            }
        }
    })
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server has been started on ${PORT}...`)
})

async function renderPosts(res, rubric) {
    let card_data = ''

    await Post.find({rubric: rubric}, function(error, docs) { 
        if (error) return console.log(error)
        
        for (let i in docs) {
            card_data +=
            `<div class="post">
                <div class="post_header">
                    <input class="post_delete" type="image" src="img/bin-delete.png" post-id="${docs[i]._id}"/>
                    <tt class="post_date">${new Date(docs[i].date).toLocaleDateString()}</tt>
                    <tt class="post_rubric">${docs[i].rubric}</tt>
                </div>
                <h3 class="post_title">${docs[i].title}</h3>
                <p class="post_text">${docs[i].text}</p>
            </div>`
        }

        fs.readFile(__dirname + "/public/main.html", (err, data) => {
            if (err) return console.log(err)

            let updatedData = data.toString().replace('{card_data}', card_data)
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
            res.end(updatedData)
        })
    })
}
```

This way we get the chain main.html -> index .js -> main.html.

Comment: You should give more details about your server part. Anyway, you can check here : https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/clients/how-to-access-query-string-parameters/

Comment: @ElJackiste, I added server code and corrected the question

Comment: @Alex - What do you get if you `console.log(req.url)`?

Comment: @JeffMcMahan, I get `/main `

Comment: @JeffMcMahan, but only when the page is refreshed and nothing happens when the link is clicked

Comment: @Alex - A raw nodejs `req.url` will include the whole query string. Your if/else conditions test for `req.url === '/main'` - which means if you send a query string, the if/else branches will always fall through to the final `else`.

Comment: @JeffMcMahan, how to fix it in my case?

Comment: Try: `req.url.startsWith('/main?')`

Answer (score 0):

Look at this logic:

> ```
> } else if (req.url === '/main' && req.method === 'GET') {
>     let rubric = url.parse(req.url, true).query.rubric
>     console.log("rubric: " + rubric) //undefined
> ```

You only try to parse the URL for a query string **if** it is an exact match for `/main`. So if it is `/main?rubric=programming` (i.e. if it actually has a query string) then it won't match.

You have a similar problem right up at the top:

> ```
> let filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'public', req.url === '/' ? 'login.html' : req.url)
> ```

---

You need to parse the URL and seperate out the path and query components of it at the very top of your server function. Then you need to do your routing based only on the path component.

Comment: How can I parse a URL and seperate out the path and query components if my `url.parse(req.url, true).query.rubric` expression is constantly undefined?

Comment: Key part of my answer: "at the very top of your server function" (although that assumes that `url.parse` does the right thing, I'd just use Express myself).

Comment: I cannot use express by the condition of the task. Ok, I understand, but what is wrong with the filePath string?

Comment: @Alex — It has the query string in it, like I said in the paragraph in the middle of the answer.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I'll try to fix this. I would put +1, but I do not have enough reputation